# Why is bash echo adding new line in find results?

Tags: bash, find, echo

When I echo the results of a find, bash is replacing the filenames' spaces with newlines. The second version shows the error. Why is that?

First version:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Bash ${BASH_VERSION}"
for f in *.txt
do
    echo "  $f"
done
```

output, no errors:

```
Bash 5.0.3(1)-release
    File 1.txt
    File 2.txt
```

Second version:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Bash ${BASH_VERSION}"
for f in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f)
do
    echo "  $f"
done
```

output with errors:

```
Bash 5.0.3(1)-release
    ./File
    1.txt
    ./File
    2.txt
```

Comment: It's nothing to do with the `echo`, it's due to the way `$(find ...)` gets split into "words" -- on whitespace of any sort. It also tries to expand anything that looks like a wildcard, which can cause *really* weird results.  See [BashFAQ: "Why you don't read lines with `for`"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and [BashFAQ #20: "How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020)

Comment: @GordonDavisson I don't get it. There's no wildcard anywhere here. `$f` is properly quoted. It's not reading the *contents* of the files. I've read your links, but still don't have a clue about what's going on.

Comment: Since `$(find ...)` isn't in double-quotes, its result is split into "words" -- not filenames, not lines, *words*. And there are four words there: "./File", "1.txt", "./File", and "2.txt". Those four words are then used by `for` as the things to loop over, so the loop runs four times; first with `f` set to "./File", then with it set to "1.txt", etc. On the other hand, if you'd double-quoted `"$(find ...)"`, then it wouldn't be split at all, and the loop would run once with `f` set to both filenames with a newline in the middle. Use one of the techniques in BashFAQ #20 instead.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thank you. I finally got it. Added my own answer, since you didn't seem interested in doing so.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use `printf` instead of `echo` because it gives more consistent behavior than `echo`.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Bash ${BASH_VERSION}"
for f in *.txt
do
printf "%s   " $f
done
```

The above program shows filenames on the same line separated by a tab and below program for newline.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Bash ${BASH_VERSION}"
for f in *.txt
do
printf "%s\n" $f
done
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It transforms spaces into tabs, and all the files get on the same line. If I use `printf " %s\n" $f` to keep each file in a separate line, the original problem returns (the spaces/tabs become newlines).

Comment: I wonder why an answer that doesn't work gets 2 upvotes, while the question gets none...

Comment: @Rodrigo Really sorry I didn't get back here soon, just some covid issue. Actually, adding of `printf "%s\n" $f` will give the right answer as I tried in my machine before giving it here.

Comment: It worked because you didn't use `find`. My error was caused when I introduced the `find`, which is the only difference between the first and second versions.

Comment: yes because the array returned by `find` is different from that of `for` loop traversal.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Gordon Davisson and [his reference](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020), I've understood it's not as trivial as it seems:

```
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' f; do
    printf "    %s\n" "$f"
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0)
```

This uses NULL byte (\0) as line delimiter, splitting the array returned by `find` at the end of each filename (instead of each space, which was the source of the error I was getting).

Comment: Wonder if there's a simpler, more intuitive way to do the same thing.